How to get account restrictions from WhatsApp Business API?
Is there a way to get the account restrictions from the Whatsapp business account api?
More specifically I want to get the account restricted in the screenshot:

I have explored the available endpoints but couldn’t find any that provide this information. I’ve tried already:
•   Checking the https://graph.facebook.com/{{api-version}}/{{business-account-id}} endpoint but it doesn’t seem to return any related info.
Reviewing the documentation but didn’t find relevant information about account restrictions.
Thanks in advance for your help!
